# Send output from child component to parent - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I'm using the following component: https://github.com/dougludlow/ng2-bs3-modal, which has an `onClose()` output event.

I'd like to do stuff on its parent component when `onClose()` is fired. Here's what I've got at the moment, but it's not working (and there are no errors either):

```
import { MODAL_DIRECTIVES, ModalComponent } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';

@Component({
    selector: 'dash-data-entry',
    template: '<modal (onClose)="reset()" #modal [size]="lg"></modal>',
    directives: [MODAL_DIRECTIVES, ModalComponent],
})

export class DashDataEntry {
   reset(){
      console.log('modal closed');
   }
}
```

When the modal is closed the `reset()` event is not triggered currently - what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the `onClose` `EventEmitter` and how you emit events.

Comment: the documentation for `onClose` states `Emits when ModalComponent.close() is called.` Do you call `ModalComponent.close()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can learn about parent-child interaction from the Angular2 docs at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly call `close()` on the modal for `onClose` to emit. There is also an `onDismiss` that emits when the modal is dismissed from either the keyboard or from clicking outside the modal.